# Linear Algebra - Prove that, if $\;A=PBP^{-1}$ and $\;A$ and $\;B$ are invertible, then $\;A^{-n}=PB^{-n}P^{-1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $\;A=PBP^{-1}$ and $\;A$ and $\;B$ are invertible, how do I prove that $\;A^{-n}=PB^{-n}P^{-1}$?

I know how to prove $\;A^n=PB^nP^{-1}$, but I don't have a good idea for proving the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*

From hypothesis we have that $B$ is invertible.

> $(ABC)^{-1}=C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$ for $A,B,C$ invertible.

Using this, you have $$(PBP^{-1})^{-1}=(P^{-1})^{-1}B^{-1}P^{-1}=PB^{-1}P^{-1}$$

So you get the result for $n=1$

Proceed with induction.

Comment: There is a typo $C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$. Just wondering, do we need $B$ is also invertible or is it implicit in the problem?

Comment: @Rajat thanks...we need it of course..we can see its invertibility by taking determinants in both sides of the equation and it is already given that $A$ is invertible..Of course the O.P must mention the invertibility of all the matricies..But we can work because if they were not invertible then the stament of the problem would not make sense at all..

Comment: Ya. I think we can infer it from invertibility of $A$. In that case, all the matrices are square matrices. Next, we can use the determinant argument as you have mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I should've perceived that. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said you know, all you need to prove is $A^{-1} = P B^{1-} P^{-1}$ (which can be done directly by checking $AA^{-1}=I$). Then $A^{-n} = (A^{-1})^n$ so you can use the equation in your last sentence.